# Prove that the set $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x^2 + y^2 > 4, y < 6\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The problem is to prove that the set $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x^2 + y^2 > 4, y < 6\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$

*My attempt*:

Let $S=(0,0)$

Let's take an arbitrary $x=(x_1,x_2) \in A$ and define $R = \min\{\lvert{d(x,S)-2}\rvert,\lvert x_2-6 \rvert \}$, so we have an open ball $K(x,R)$
To prove that the set is open we need to prove that for an arbitrary $y=(y_1,y_2) \in K(x,R)$ that $y$ has to be in $A$.

By a few manipulations, mainly using the triangle inequality and the points $S,x,y$ I've managed to prove that $y_1^2+y_2^2 > 4$.

But proving $y_2 < 6$ has proven to be very difficult and I'm left without ideas as to what to do specifically.I have a feeling I'm missing something much simpler here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $y\in K(x,R)$
$$
y_2<x_2+R\leq x_2+|x_2-6|
$$
Now as $x\in A$, $x_2<6$, hence $|x_2-6|=6-x_2$. And we conclude.
$$
y_2<x_2+6-x_2=6
$$

I think you did the tricky part (That was actually finding R)

Comment: The simplest answers are usually the best, can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach.

Notice that $A = B \cap C$, where $B= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 :x^2 + y^2 >4 \}$, and $C=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : y < 6 \}$. Since the intersection of two open sets is open, you only need to show that $B$ and $C$ are open.

It may also be easier to show that $B^c$ and $C^c$ are closed.

Answer (score 0):

If $y_2\geq 6$, then $d(x,y)\geq y_2-x_2\geq 6-x_2\geq R$,

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
6-x_2 &= 6 - y_2 + (y_2 - x_2)\\
&\le 6 - y_2 + |y_2 - x_2|\\
&\le 6 - y_2 + d\big((y_1,y_2),(x_1,x_2)\big)\\
&< 6 - y_2 + |x_2 - 6|\\
\end{align}

This implies $$6 - y_2 > 6 - x_2 - |x_2 - 6| \ge 6 - x_2 - (6 - x_2) =  0$$ so $y_2 < 6$.